# How do I add memcached session save path to open_basedir in PHP

Tags: php, memcached

I have a number of sites where previous developers have used memcached for sessions. All was working fine until recently when I had to update my `open_basedir` setting in php.ini to get file uploads working across our sites.

The sites that use memcached for sessions work but no session data is being saved. I was getting the open_basedir restriction error but I added `127.0.0.1:11211` to the `open_basedir` and it stopped these errors but no sessions are being saved.

How can I find the path to use in open_basedir for memcached to save sessions in memcached?